# why does jsFiddle not like this loop?

Tags: javascript, document.write, fiddle

There seems to be some serious problems with the difference between the fiddles and the kind of javascript statements that actually *work* when ran on servers.  Can you guys help me solve this?  I've run into this countless times in last few months.  Here's what I have:

```
<script>
int counter;
int retainer = 0;

for (counter = 1; counter < 10; counter++) {
    retainer = retainer + counter;
}
document.write(retainer);
</script>
```

can someone tell me why this gives me a blank page when run in a browser?  does the `WRITE()` method not working in this way?

Comment: *"can someone tell me why this gives me a blank page when run in a browser?"* Because you have `int` instead of `let` or `var`. It won't work in any JavaScript environment.

Comment: _"can someone tell me..."_ - Your browser will do so in the console.

Comment: thank you.  i forgot that!  so, how can I get a check of errors when running tests on my js code?  I am using eclipse as an IDE.

Comment: @AdamEvanovich - I would use an IDE with good JavaScript support. I don't know about Eclipse. vscode and WebStorm are both great.

Comment: thanks!  I will download those!

Answer (score 0):

There is no int in javascript. All variables are declared using "var"(till ES5) instead irrespective of datatype. Javascript is dynamically typed language. "let" and "const" have been introduced from ES6 onwards

```
<script>
var counter;
var retainer = 0;

for (counter = 1; counter < 10; counter++) {
    retainer = retainer + counter;
}
document.write(retainer);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it's a js code, there is no `int` in javascript as I remember

Comment: thank you.  i forgot that!  so, how can I get a check of errors when running tests on my js code?  I am using eclipse as an IDE.

Comment: `try {
your code here
} catch(e) {
console.log('this would be your exception ', e);
}`
I think this is what you need

Comment: @NarekGevorgyan - No, you can't catch syntax errors.

Comment: you're right. So if you're talking about syntax errors thats another story. there are tools like `jslint` also modern IDEs also recognize js syntax errors. Or use typescript for type safety.